# too long waiting for fence

Tags: c#, vulkan

I am using Vulkan with C# and Silk.net. And can't understand why it takes so long to complete even small command queues. Please, look at this **CPU** timeline:

[image]

As you can see, there are too long waitings, while **GPU** work times are small:

[image]

I understand that it is not efficient to wait for fences. But here is something strange, I think. When it was OpenGL, it was possible to synchronize CPU and GPU after every draw. Even with different shaders, textures, and much of work. So, it must be possible without such waiting.

Is it some bug or normal behaviour for Vulkan?

Comment: Please add some more details. Synchronization in Vulkan is explicit, so stuff like this is usually caused by the application. So no, this is neither a bug nor normal for Vulkan.

Comment: "*When it was OpenGL, it was possible to synchronize CPU and GPU after every draw. Even with different shaders, textures, and much of work. So, it must be possible without such waiting.*" What makes you think that happened without "such waiting?" What were you doing that required such synchornization every frame? Also, the times in your example are on the order of tenths of a millisecond. That level of overhead is not surprising for a heavyweight synchronization option. You can't expect the CPU thread to wake up *instantly* when the GPU operation it is waiting on is complete.

Comment: @SaschaWillems Sorry, but there is nothing to show as details. Just simple sumbits with waiting for their fence under them.

Comment: @NicolBolas I made the same work on OpenGL and Vulkan. I mean that it draw the same rectangles with the same shaders and textures. And it switches to CPU after every work, like it was. So I thought that I can make it possible to happen without Vulkan-specific logick to avoid such a problem.

Comment: @Trop: "*I mean that it draw the same rectangles with the same shaders and textures.*" Do you issue a `glFinish` after you render everything on each frame? Because that's the equivalent of waiting for a fence in Vulkan.

Comment: @NicolBolas No. I am doing just this: Vk.ResetFences, then Vk.QueueSubmit, then Vk.WaitForFences. No other steps between.

Comment: @Trop: You compared your Vulkan code to OpenGL. That comparison is invalid unless you're also inducing the equivalent CPU stall in OpenGL as your Vulkan code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vulkan does not specify behavior in terms of timing. So this is neither a "bug" nor "normal". Performance questions of this sort are not a matter of the API definition. They are a matter of reasonable expectation out of a system.

The delay times you are talking about appear to be on the order of tenths of a millisecond. That is not entirely unreasonable as far as overhead is concerned for waiting on an unsignaled fence. It is not reasonable to expect the CPU thread to be woken up instantly upon the completion of the GPU operation being waited on.

Waiting on an unsignaled fence is only something that should happen if the CPU starts outrunning the GPU. You should only check a fence from a previous frame, and only if you need to use some memory resources or swapchain images used by that frame. And if it is still unsignaled, go do whatever CPU work you can that doesn't require using those resources. Only when you are out of other work to do should you actually wait on the fence with a non-zero time.

Comment: Thank you. I think I don't understand Vulkan at all. Because I can't imagine how to make a new submission, if it depends of previous step. If I change the same resources of that steps without that fences, I thought that it would be incorrect state before current work is complete.

Comment: @Trop: The standard solution is some form of multi-buffering. That is, you have multiple regions of memory that you can write to, and you pick one that isn't currently in use. If the oldest one is still in use by the GPU (as determined by checking the fence), then you must wait on the fence or go do something non-graphics related. Essentially, the CPU is a frame ahead of the GPU, writing to different regions of memory than the ones the GPU is currently consuming.

Comment: OpenGL will often do buffering for you. If you invalidate buffer objects, or reallocate them, or sometimes just upload to the whole storage while it is currently in use, the system will allocate more memory to use as a buffer. It will then schedule an upload to the actual GPU memory resource once the GPU has finished using it. Vulkan is lower-level, so if you want that kind of thing, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: It is much harder. I even can't make it work yet with semaphores and unchanged resources :) . Many bugs every frame, which is very very specific. Will try again. Thanks for clarification.